Cannot use GPU for custom spaCy NER model
I'm trying to make a custom NER model using spaCy. When I try to leverage gpu it throws an error stating that Cupy is not installed even though it is. Attaching relevant info below.
> ubuntu@:~$ nvcc --version
> nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
> Copyright (c) 2005-2021 NVIDIA Corporation Built on
> Thu_Nov_18_09:45:30_PST_2021 Cuda compilation tools, release 11.5,
> V11.5.119 Build cuda_11.5.r11.5/compiler.30672275_0

installed cupy as pip install cupy-cuda12x
ubuntu@:~$ pip show cupy-cuda12x
Name: cupy-cuda12x
Version: 13.1.0
Summary: CuPy: NumPy & SciPy for GPU
Home-page: https://cupy.dev/
Author: Seiya Tokui
Author-email: tokui@preferred.jp
License: MIT License
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages
Requires: fastrlock, numpy
Required-by: cucim-cu12, cudf-cu12, cugraph-cu12, cuml-cu12, cuproj-cu12, cuxfilter-cu12, dask-cudf-cu12

GPU Error
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[13], line 7
      4 import spacy
      5 from spacy.tokens import DocBin
----> 7 spacy.require_gpu()
      9 #nlp = spacy.blank("en") # load a new spacy model
     10 nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm") # load other spacy model

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/thinc/util.py:230, in require_gpu(gpu_id)
    228     raise ValueError("Cannot use GPU, PyTorch is not installed")
    229 elif platform.system() != "Darwin" and not has_cupy:
--> 230     raise ValueError("Cannot use GPU, CuPy is not installed")
    231 elif not has_gpu:
    232     raise ValueError("No GPU devices detected")

ValueError: Cannot use GPU, CuPy is not installed

I've tried installing both cupy versions (cuda11x and cuda12x) but the result is the same. Any suggestions?

Please post the code and an error as a text, not a screenshot.

Resolved it by installing the required modules from the cupy documentation.

Which ones? This is not a useful answer.

cuDNN and NCCL wasn't installed
